# In case of a dc shunt motor, can you use the back emf equation(Eb=ZNPPhi/60A) for the shunt winding (field winding)?

Tags: motor, dc, shunt

In case of a dc shunt motor, can you use the back emf equation(Eb=ZNPPhi/60A) for the shunt winding (field winding)?

Comment: There is no Back-EMF induced in the field winding. So no.